# I'm not sure how to move two divs into a sidebar, or how to make a sidebar - HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, image, sidebar

So I've been building a collection of webpages with mainly HTML only, and I've decided to add a 'Back to start' div at the top, which is linked to the Welcome page. It currently appears above the header and question at the edge of the page, and this makes it push down the rest of the content, leaving a big gap along the top. 
  In other words, a div is pushing all my content down, when I'd rather have it aligned with the header which is otherwise the usual top of the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>

    <title>Question 5</title>

    <div class="leftbox">

        <a href="file:///G:/Business/Business%20Sector%20Quiz/Welcome.html">

            <div style="width: 80px; height: 40px; padding: 2.5px" float: left>

                <p> ← Back to start</p>

            </div>

        </a>

        <a href="file:///G:/Business/Business%20Sector%20Quiz/Question%204.html">

            <div style="width: 100px; height: 40px; padding: 2.5px" float: left>

                <p> ← Back 1 question</p>

            </div>

        </a>

    </div>
```

I haven't managed to do this using the  method as my CSS formats any divs, so I end up with a long strip down the left side which is formatted.

So what I'm asking is, does anyone know how to move my divs over to the side aligned with the header, or how to get around the div class="left" issue I have? Thanks - Oisin

Note: I apologise if I am being overly vague or not very specific with my question - I'm not too sure about HTML formatting, and about website building. Also, if you need to read some more code or see more about my website, just ask; I still have all the files.

[image: As you can see, the two divs shown are higher than my header, causing a big space above them. Is there a way to align it with the headers and get rid of this blank 'header'?]

Comment: Also - the header 'Question 2', the question itself and the image is in a table.

Comment: The float property need to be inside the quotes (style).

Comment: Also, it is not the best practice to declare the style inside the HTML elements.

Comment: I can't use CSS to style these divs, as there are other divs at the bottom of the page and throughout other pages.

Answer (score 1):

the div with the class `.leftbox` needs to be floated left since it contains all the anchor links and it is the parent for all header elements

other issues with your html (you have `float:left` outside of your style)

```
div style="width: 80px; height: 40px; padding: 2.5px" float: left>

 <div style="width: 100px; height: 40px; padding: 2.5px" float: left>
```

**here is a snippet**

```css
.leftbox{
  float:left;
}
```

```html
    <title>Question 5</title>
    <div class="leftbox">
        <a href="file:///G:/Business/Business%20Sector%20Quiz/Welcome.html">
            <div style="width: 80px; height: 40px; padding: 2.5px">
                <p> ← Back to start</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="file:///G:/Business/Business%20Sector%20Quiz/Question%204.html">
            <div style="width: 100px; height: 40px; padding: 2.5px" >
                <p> ← Back 1 question</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <p>
    <h1>
    This is the header
    </h1>
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTAvG8n4pH7Awr-5ISF1rif1RQMv8Rko1zTctYDaARiYOCJi4TDhY5ye1w'
    </p>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as the divs are still above the header, and my CSS styles all divs to have background and border colour, so I'm left with 2 divs inside a div. I'll share my new code soon.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle with all of your codes so that i can debug or if your codes are not that lengthy can you post full codes in your question so that i can look at it? :D

Comment: Sure- I'll do it as soon as I can.